# how to detect color white in ycrcb?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, color-space

i want to detect white object using open cv in python, but i have problem to define lower white and upper white in ycbcr. i try to make program but the program doesn't get right result to detect an object. this my code:

```
 ycrcb = cv.cvtColor(rgb, cv.COLOR_BGR2YCrCb)
 lower_white = np.array([205, 128, 128], dtype=np.uint8)
 upper_white = np.array([235, 128, 128], dtype=np.uint8)
 img = cv.inRange(ycrcb, lower_white, upper_white)
```

and i try to detect using structuring element and send to morphology :

```
se_3 = cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_RECT,(3,3))
dst_dilate = cv.dilate(img, se_3, iterations = 1)
```

and put it together using bitwise and:

```
res = cv.bitwise_and(rgb,rgb, mask= dst_dilate)
```

i try my best but the result is incorrect, i need your opinion which part to change and get better result.

[image: the object is all birds]

Comment: what do you know about the YUV/YCC spaces? why do you think your upper and lower bounds make sense?

Comment: I don't know it very well

Comment: then you might want to read about it. both wikipedia and opencv's own documentation talk _a little bit_ about it. you are looking for an explanation of the value ranges, and what they mean.

Comment: yes, but just a little documentation regarding the color of ycbcr

Comment: seriously? the wikipedia page contains equations, formulas, constants, illustrations, .... everything https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr did you not visit this link before? are you looking for someone to write the code for you? you can probably find the "Color conversions" documentation of opencv, which contains more formulas and constants -- the only issue with opencv is that they got the color codes the wrong way around. customarily it's blue, then red, so YCbCr

Comment: nope, I've written my code above and I just want to ask if something is wrong in my code

Comment: yes, there's something wrong with the code, and that is, as I already pointed out, the upper and lower bounds to cvtColor, which are pointless, because these bounds cover the entire value range. -- you don't get an error. if you got an error, you should have posted the error message. what you get is simply a completely filled/white mask. which you also didn't show. please [edit] your post and show the issues.

Comment: still the wrong bounds. Y ranges 0 to 255 so you're selecting a narrow range of dark gray. and white is around 128 in both chromas.

Comment: yes, I still haven't found it

Comment: I said *around* 128, not exactly 128, and what's even the picture? just show the picture.

Comment: i have added it

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to do this is to load your image, convert it to your desired colourspace and split the channels, laying them out side-by-side. Then use your system's *"colour-dropper tool"* (*"Digital Color Meter"* on macOS) to look at the values of the individual channels in the areas that interest you:

```
import cv2

# Load image
im = cv2.imread('qAK68.jpg')

# Convert to YCrCb colourspace
YCrCb = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCrCb)

# Split channels and lay out side-by-sise, Y on the left, Cr then Cb on the right
Y, Cr, Cb = cv2.split(YCrCb)
hstack = np.hstack((Y,Cr,Cb))
```

[image]

You should see you need roughly the following ranges:

- `Y` 60..255
- `Cr` 120..136
- `Cb` 120..136

---

If you don't have a *"Color Dropper"* tool, just go to **ImageJ** online tool [here](https://ij.imjoy.io) and upload my output image below and mouse over it to see the values like this:

[image]

---

If you are on Linux, you can get a colour dropper called `gpick` with:

```
sudo apt install gpick
```